# Streaming videos with HTML5 player- Multiple video chunks as single video

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, video-streaming

I am using the following C# code to stream video chunks. **GetVideoBytes()** gets bytes of video content from another domain.

**C#**

```
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public void GetVideoChunkContent()
        {
        byte[] videoChunk =GetVideoBytes();
        if (videoChunk.Count() == 0)
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(videoChunk, 0, videoChunk.Length);
       }
```

**Html**

```
<video controls=""><source type="video/mp4" src="ClientSideMethods.asmx/GetVideoChunkContent"></video>
```

The video is getting played in the html5 player, but replaying , seeking etc are not working.
Also I want to implement playing a set of video chunks together as a single video. 
How can I achieve these two requirements?